# PHP: Variable inside function use it outside function?

Tags: php

Im including almost every page in page_protect(); . I have made an variable for the userid, $userid, with the user´s id. So it will be much easier for me to get the id than calling SESSION_id each time on every page.

How can i use a variable inside that function outside the function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function page_protect()
{
  global $id;
  $id = 1234;
}

page_protect();
echo $id;
```

Comment: I know this answer was written almost 4 years ago, but I'd like to add this as a note for future visitors: You shouldn't use `global`s anymore. [They're evil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/1438393).

Comment: @AmalMurali, agreed, it's better to use function parameters and return values. But let people walk before they run.